# Raspberry Chromium v88 (88.0.4324.187) keeps crashing (Error code : 11)

Tags: pi-3b+, chromium

I have problems with kiosk application on Raspberry. I'm using chromium as digital signage presentation. System was working fine, until few days ago. I get crash report Error code 11.
From error log, I can see pattern, which happens just before crash.

> [572:572:0706/145218.003604:VERBOSE1:chrome_password_manager_client.cc(1349)] RenderFrameDeleted: this: 0xad23000"

> [572:572:0706/145218.003794:VERBOSE1:chrome_password_manager_client.cc(1350)] rfh: 0xd92f800

> [572:572:0706/145218.003891:VERBOSE1:chrome_password_manager_client.cc(1351)] rfh->GetView(): (nil)

It happens randomly. Chromium 78.0.3904.108 works fine for a year now.
Log file: https://pastebin.com/D6zECKAY

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by uninstalling chromium-browser package with
`sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n` and installing new package, which have been renamed in chromium-browser.
`sudo apt-get install chromium`.

I've also tried a workaround before fixing, to launch chromium-browser with the undocumented option `--no-sandbox`

Hope it helps you.

Michele

Comment: I think your answer has a error, `sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n` twice ?

Comment: Yes  @MatsK you're right. Obliviously the second command have to be sudo apt-get install. It was a mistake of cut and paste. I edit the answer below